# Single < next to filename in bash

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I'm trying to make sense of [this application](https://stackoverflow.com) of the sed command:

```
sed -f <(printf 's/%s/%s/g\n' $(<patterns.txt)) <(head -n 1000 contents.txt) >newcontents.txt
```

In particular I don't quite understand what `<patterns.txt` does. I'm finding nothing on the web and I don't know what to look for. What is `<` in that sense?

Comment: `$(<patterns.txt)` is equivalent to `$(cat patterns.txt)`, but faster.

Comment: Documented here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

Comment: And https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html, in case you were wondering about the other one too.

Comment: Thanks @M.NejatAydin. Care to formulate an answer? Is this also documented somewhere?
I'm familiar with the concept of process and command substitution.

Comment: @glades The answer is in the documentation links in the other comments. That is, [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) and [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Ahh now I see it, thank you! I meant that you formulate the answer so I can make it the accepted answer.

Comment: @glades I could, but this would be just a repetition of the mentioned documents.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) documentation the command is part of a command substitution and executes the `cat` command on the file:

> The command substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent
> but faster $(< file).